# Convert spherical coordinate equation to rectangular coordinates?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

Find an equation in rectangular coordinates for the equation given in spherical coordinates:
$\phi=\pi/6$

Equation must be such that $z \ge 0$.

Here is what I did:

$z = \rho\cos\phi$

$z = \cos{\pi/6}\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 + z^2}$

and since z must be greater than or equal to zero:

z = $| \cos{\pi/6}\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 + z^2} |$

Answer (score 1):

Please note how your expression of $z$ is already positive, you don't need absolute values. Else, your expression is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an equation in $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ whose solution is the desired surface,
so it's technically correct, provided that we interpret $\cos \pi/6$ as
$\cos(\pi/6)$ and not $(\cos\pi)/6.$
You might also want to format your expression carefully so that someone doesn't think you meant $\cos\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{6}\right)$ or even
$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right).$

I think this works well to remove those ambiguities:
$z = \left\lvert\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\cos\frac{\pi}{6}\right\rvert.$

You could still do a lot to simplify the expression, however.
As has already been pointed, out, the absolute value is redundant since
$\cos\frac{\pi}{6} > 0$ and since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is non-negative by definition of the square root function.
But the fact that you have a square root suggests you might try to see what happens if you square both sides. If you do that, and if you use the well-known value of
$\cos\frac{\pi}{6},$ you might find that things simplify quite a bit
(although the danger of squaring is that it sometimes allows solutions you don't want, and in this case it forces you to explicitly require that $z \geq 0$).